# Allow EntityManagerFactory injection to be null when database service is off

Tags: hibernate, jpa, dependency-injection, jersey, jax-rs

I have a Jersey web service that uses Hibernate to do some persistence.  I have implemented creation/disposal of the EntityManagerFactory using hk2 provider logic I found a stack overflow, which has greatly helped keep the number of DB connections low.  I don't want to force users to have a DB, so I want the code to gracefully handle that case.  However, I can't seem to figure it out, other than having to comment out my @Inject annotation.  Anyone know how to use a custom @Inject and code it to allow that to be null?

I tried to catch that exception in DBManager when Persistence.create fails and just check for null in my WebServiceClass.  But it crashes at the @Inject line and the exception is not caught.  I looked around at that findOrCreate null exception and saw there is a method called supportsNullCreation() but have not found examples on how to use it.

This is what my code looks like:

Injectable DB Provider using HK2:

```
public class DbManager 
        implements Factory<EntityManagerFactory>
{
   private static EntityManagerFactory factory = null;

   @Inject
   public DbManager()
   {
      try
      {
         factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myapp");
      }
      catch ( Exception eee )
      {
         // just means DB is not connected which I want to allow
         System.out.println("No DB, that should be okay");
      }
   }

   @Override
   public EntityManagerFactory provide() {
      return factory;
   }

   @Override
   public void dispose(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
      if ( emf != null && emf.isOpen() )
      {
         emf.close();
      }
   }

   public EntityManagerFactory getEntityMgrFactory()
   {
      return factory;
   }
}
```

Then here is how the provider is created in the Jersey app:

```
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig 
{
    public MyApplication()
    {

        ....

    // Provider of DB
    this.register( new AbstractBinder()
    {
       @Override
       public void configure()
       {
 bindFactory(DbManager.class).to(EntityManagerFactory.class).in(Singleton.class);
       }
    });
}
```

Then it is used like this:

```
@Singleton
@Path("myservice")
public class WebServiceClass
{

   // NOTE: Right now I have to comment this to run without a DB
   @Inject
   private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = null;
   ...
```

The exception I get is this...

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context 
 org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext@6cae5847 findOrCreate returned a null for 
descriptor SystemDescriptor(
    implementation=com.db.DbManager
    contracts={javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory}
    scope=javax.inject.Singleton
    qualifiers={}
    descriptorType=PROVIDE_METHOD
    descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
    metadata=
    rank=0
    loader=org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder$2@7050f2b1
    proxiable=null
    proxyForSameScope=null
    analysisName=null
    id=145
    locatorId=0
    identityHashCode=863132354
    reified=true)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2075)
...
```

Comment: So with your example, are you saying that if the EMF creation were to fail, you still want it to work ok, meaning the injection will just be null? What would be the benefit in this? Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: I guess the question is how would the users interact with the service without the db? What do the calls to the endpoints return?

Comment: Yes, I want it to work okay when the EMF creation fails.

Comment: The calls to the endpoint returns some data to the user which may or may not be persisted, depending on if a DB is installed and running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is dynamic injection of EMF dependency. Normally all injections are static, it means all dependencies are wired when the object that depends on them is created.

An easy solution with any dependency injection mechanism, not only with HK2, is to create a wrapper object, that would hold reference to the real dependency, or null if the dependency is not available. The same may be achieved by wrapping the EntityManagerFactory into a collection of one or zero elements. It could look like this:

```
// factory wrapper
public class EMFHolder {
   private EntityManagerFactory emf;
   public EMFHolder(EntityManagerFactory emf) { this.emf = emf;}
   public EntityManagerFactory getEmf() { return this.emf; 
}

// provider
public class DbManager implements Factory<EntityManagerFactory> {
 // ... 
   @Override
   public EMFHolder provide() {
      return new EMFHolder(factory);
   }
 // ...
}

// using factory if not null
public class WebServiceClass
{
   @Inject
   private EMFHolder emfHolder;

   public void doComethingWithEMF() {
     if (emfHolder.getEmf() != null) {
        // do something with the factory...
     }
   }
}
```

Also have a look at HK2 [Iterable Provider](https://hk2.java.net/2.4.0-b31/introduction.html#IterableProvider), but I don't think it will allow you to return a null value from your `provide` method.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [Null Object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

Using that pattern, if no database exists you can in configuration register your `Null Object` implementation of `Factory<EntityManagerFactory>` instead of `DbManager`.

Comment: I could use more detail.  I tried creating a NullableDbMgr, but the provide() method is supposed to return null for EntityManagerFactory right?  If so, it causes the same problem.  Are you saying I should provide something different?  If so, doesn't that ruin the effectiveness of the provider?

Comment: Yes, you should also create `Null Object` implementation of `EntityManagerFactory` to use it when there is no database. This should warn you, if `EntityManagerFactory` isn't my own interface why I use it directly in my consuming classes? Aparat from that, to solve your case, you may also consider using in-memory database.

Comment: The idea with null object is that you will not return null from `provide` method, but you will create your own implementation of `EntityManagerFactory` interface, with empty methods (that may throw runtime exception for example). In the client code, you will try to to check whether such empty object was received. If yes, it means there is no connection to the database. Otherwise you will use injected EMF object as usual.